# PySpark : How to take a sample RDD from a huge RDD?

Tags: apache-spark, rdd, pyspark

I was looking for debugging option while working on a function that takes RDD as its parameter. Since have a huge RDD I would like to take a subset of it to develop the function.

How can i make a subset of an RDD ?
The new sample should be a RDD ?

Answer (score 2):

Oh!

I got it we can use sample function

```
sample(self, withReplacement, fraction, seed=None)
```

Return a sampled subset of this RDD (relies on numpy and falls back on default random generator if numpy is unavailable).